# YOLOv3-tensorflow not converging

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, loss-function, yolo

I am trying to implement YOLOv3 in tensorflow, I have taken help from online repositories and was successful in converting the darknet weights to tensorflow and run inference.
Now, I am trying to train the model using the YOLO loss as implemented [here](https://github.com/maiminh1996/YOLOv3-tensorflow/blob/master/loss_function.py).

I am using the following code snipppet to do so:

```
    with tf.name_scope('Loss_and_Detect'):
        yolo_loss = compute_loss(output, y_true, anchors, config.num_classes, print_loss=False)
        tf.summary.scalar('YOLO_loss', yolo_loss)
        variables = tf.trainable_variables()

        # Variables to be optimized by train_op if the pre-trained darknet-53 is used as is
        if config.pre_train:
            variables = variables[312:] # Get the weights after the 52nd conv-layer (darknet-53)

                  # 5e-4 as used in the paper
        l2_loss = config.weight_decay * tf.add_n([tf.nn.l2_loss(tf.cast(v, dtype=tf.float32)) for v in variables]) 
        loss = yolo_loss + l2_loss
        tf.summary.scalar('L2_loss', l2_loss)
        tf.summary.scalar('Total_loss', loss)

    # Define an optimizer for minimizing the computed loss
    with tf.name_scope('Optimizer'):
        update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
        with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
            optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)

    update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)

    with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
        train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss=loss, global_step=global_step, var_list=variables)
```

The problem is my YOLO_loss is stuck at ~7-8 and the L2_loss keeps on increasing.

[Here is a snapshot of the tensorboard with learning rate 1e-6 with exponential decay applied to it.(decay_rate=0.8)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XHyy.png)

I cannot figure out what an I missing/doing wrong.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I got a 404 on the github link you shared. Is there any resource I can refer to while implementing YOLO loss. Any help is appreciated.